# Focus loop on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click on a button in my web app a new div[contenteditable] is created and focus is set on it. It works. The problem is if I click on my button several times in a row very quickly, the browser will freak out and set focus on all of the created divs and never stop in an endless loop. How can I prevent this from happening?

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-create-div', function(e) {
    $.ajax(...).done(function(data) {
        $('#divs').prepend('<div contenteditable data-id="' + data.id + '">');
        $('#divs').find('div[data-id="' + data.id + '"]').focus();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an infinite loop, the code will be executed as many times you clicked the button so if you click it rapidly it will indeed be a long time before everything catches up.
What you could do is disable the button on click then enable it back after x amount of seconds if you want to prevent this.

Comment: It wouldn’t be a problem if it was just as many times as you click. At least in firefox it keeps focusing between the different divs forever. Looping over and over. The disable idea is good though! Thanks! I’ll try it and see if that is fast enough or if I need a settimout on top of it! Other ideas are welcome too.

Comment: I needed a timeout of 250 as well, but that did it! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you click to the button many times at the "same time", it will make to many http requests, then the requests finish at the same time too (maybe). Finally, to many div tag will be create and be focus (behavior of contenteditable will be different with input tag - I think so).

I have 2 options for that situation:

1. Try to make `focus` command run in a "order". Wrap `focus` action into `setTimeout`.

   ```
   setTimeout(function() {
       $('#divs').find('div[data-id="' + data.id + '"]').focus();
   }, 0);
   ```
2. `Debounce` click action. User can click to many times, but click action will not be call many times. (Recommended)

   Delay 250ms for each action...

   ```
   $(document).on('click', '.btn-create-div', $.debounce(250, function(e) {
       $.ajax(...).done(function(data) {
          $('#divs').prepend('<div contenteditable data-id="' + data.id + '">');
          $('#divs').find('div[data-id="' + data.id + '"]').focus();
       });
   }));
   ```

Comment: 1. gave same result and 2. gave me `TypeError: t.debounce is not a function`. Do I need a separate jQuery library? Will try to disable the button and enabling it again like the other reply suggested too. Thanks